# Getting member variables values set and then passed to a function c++

Tags: c++, function, variables, constructor

Probably a dumb question, I want to be able to use the passed in A & B values through the default constructor and use them in my functions like get(), but every time i do it gives the value of 0, how do i set the values of A & B and then be able to use them in my other functions. I know i could just pass the value into the get function from the main but i dont want to do it that way.

I have this in the .h,

```
class example
{
private:
    int A, B;

public:
    example();
    example(int, int);
    int get(int, int);
};
```

then in the .cpp

```
example::example()
{
    cout << hello;
}
example::example(int x, int y)
{
    A = x;
    B = y;
}

int example::get(int c, int d)
{
    int k = c + d / A;

    return k;
}
```

And in the main()

```
int c = 10;
int d = 12;
int x = 2;
int y = 1;

example obj1(x, y);

example obj2;
int k = obj2.get(c, d);

cout << k;
```

Im thinking i should see an answer of 10 + 12 / 2 however its 10 + 12 / 0, not sure where i am going wrong if anyone could help thanks!

Comment: That code won't compile.  `example obj1` default constructs and example object but you have not defined a default constructor.  Also what does `example(x, y)` do?

Comment: I want to pass the values of x, y to the private A & B variables and then use them in functions if that makes any sense

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Check out vsoftco's answer.

Comment: you never set `obj2.A` anywhere, but `obj2.get` uses that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
example(x, y);
```

does not do anything. It creates a temporary object that goes immediately out of scope. Then

```
example obj1;
```

should not compile, as you don't have a default constructor. If it compiles it means that you have provided a default constructor, which is invoked (and which probably doesn't do any initialization). However in your case you want to invoke the constructor `example::example(int, int)`. The correct way of doing it is to define

```
example obj1(x, y);
```

Comment: I have added in a default constructor and edited the main, does this change anything and should this compile correctly now what you are seeing as i am still having issues. cheers

Comment: @Sup `example obj2;` again constructs a non-initialized object. Pass the values that you want to initialize it with, example `example obj2(10,20);`.

Comment: Thanks I finally got my head around it!